# solve a mathematical expression about a specific unknown parameter with python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, symbols, equation

I have this equation

[image]

and want to solve it about `t` with Python, `numpy`. First of all I should say that in this equation:

*<<h r ai hint T*=1000 tau=t/t*>>*

is known. Before I ask the question here I used symbols methods in `numpy`: I explained `t` as a symbol but I get this

`Error :cannot convert expression to float`

The code that I wrote for the case that I have `t` and I want to calculate `h` is here:

```
def h_t(h=None,t=None):
    if h==None:
        term1 = np.sum([coeav[i] / (i + 1) * (t/1000)**(i + 1) for i in range(7)])
        term2 = coeav[7] * np.log(t/1000)
        term3 = np.sum([(coeav[i] / (7 - i)) * (1/(t/1000))**(i - 7) for i in range(8, 13)])
    elif t==None:
        
        
        return ((term1+term2+term3)*1000+hint/r)*r
```

Comment: If t is not None your function return nothing.

Comment: I was able to calculate your terms without any issue using `t = 1` and `coeav = 1` for all indices. We need more details on what exactly are you passing as `t` and as `coeav`.

Comment: @MichaelCao thanks for your cooperating. coaev=[17.190126419067383
-11.550975799560547
7.005699634552002
-2.86214280128479
0.7931802868843079
-0.13392554223537445
0.010209172032773495
-8.967597007751465
3.3796420097351074
-0.7651314735412598
0.10340806096792221
-0.007709052879363298
0.0002440817333990708]   r= 8.31415 h=17609 . and the problem is to find t for given h

Comment: I thought you were calculating h? I don't believe an analytic solution for t is possible here. You have an exponential and a log term here. Also, I'm still unable to replicate the above error.

Comment: If you are okay with a numerical solution for t, I suggest checking out [scipy.optimize.fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) and come back to us with your attempted solution and any specific questions.

Comment: @MichaelCao all i want is to use this calculation that I used for calculating h but let t as a symbol and at last with known h and unknown t solve the expression about t.thanks for your time sir

Comment: What do you mean by `t as a symbol`?  Is is a `sympy.symbol`?  Don't mix `sympy` and `numpy` - unless you know what you are doing. And use `if h is None:` in your tests, not `==`.

Comment: @Abbas Zandi still don't know what is meant this `<<h r ai hint T*=1000 tau=t/t*>>`, what is _hint_?

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> coaev=[17.190126419067383, -11.550975799560547, 7.005699634552002, -2.862142
80128479, 0.7931802868843079, -0.13392554223537445, 0.010209172032773495, -8.967
597007751465, 3.3796420097351074, -0.7651314735412598 ,0.10340806096792221 ,-0.0
07709052879363298 ,0.0002440817333990708]; r= 8.31415; h=17609
>>> coeav=coaev
>>> var('hint t')
(hint, t)
>>> term1 = sum([coeav[i] / (i + 1) * (t/1000)**(i + 1) for i in range(7)])
>>> term2 = coeav[7] * log(t/1000)
>>> term3 = sum([(coeav[i] / (7 - i)) * (1/(t/1000))**(i - 7) for i in range(8,
13)])
>>> eq = ((term1+term2+term3)*1000+hint/r)*r

Look for a good guess near solution

>>> eq.subs(hint,h).subs(t,1).n()
-390126303482586.
>>> eq.subs(hint,h).subs(t,11).n()
-1616907300.09601
>>> eq.subs(hint,h).subs(t,111).n()
73731.7541309398

OK, got a sign change so guess in the middle

>>> nsolve(eq.subs(hint,h),50)  # assuming you mean hint = h
54.5730717247901
```